# Merge hybris into sap-commerce-cloud, based on product's new name

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I want to add a synonym for [hybris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hybris). This product was bought by SAP a few years ago and is now call [sap-commerce-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-commerce-cloud).

I can't add [sap-commerce-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-commerce-cloud) in [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hybris/synonyms) because someone already add [hybris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hybris) as a synonym of [sap-commerce-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-commerce-cloud).

That's actually fine but the issue is that I can't upvote the suggested synonym because I didn't answer enough [sap-commerce-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-commerce-cloud) questions...

The upvote should take account of both tags, most users have answered questions with the old tag ([hybris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hybris)) and not the new one ([sap-commerce-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-commerce-cloud)).

---

***Edit***

I realize that I'm asking two topics there :

- Fix the [hybris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hybris) / [sap-commerce-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-commerce-cloud) synonyms
- Find a new way to manage upvotes on synonym

This post is for the first topic and I will open an other one as a feature-request

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the specific goal of this question. Do you want to 1) make a [meta-tag:feature-request] so that the source tag's score is also counted for tag synonym approval, or 2) request a mod's [meta-tag:support] to approve the synonym single-handedly?

Comment: Hello @AndrewT., yes I would like that a mod approve this specific synonym request. Then I think the synonym feature would need an improvement. I didn't flag this post as feature-request because this is not my first goal.

Comment: Those are 2 quite different requests, @alain.janinm . There's nothing wrong with either, but they should be 2 separate questions. I would suggest rewording this question to he asking for the synonym on the tags, and then asking a new one for the [[tag:feature-request]] and [[tag:discussion]] on the ability to request a synonym to consider a users score on both tags for eligibility to vote.

Comment: I'm confused by the request. You seem to be requesting a synonym "for [hybris]" which I'm reading as [sap-commerce-cloud] -> [hybris]. But if the name of the product is now SAP Commerce Cloud wouldn't the (already proposed) synonym [hybris] -> [sap-commerce-cloud] make more sense?

Comment: To make sure I haven't misunderstood before I pull the trigger on merging one into the other, do you want [tag:sap-commerce-cloud] as the main tag?

Comment: Hello @ZoestandswithUkraine, yes the proper name is [tag:sap-commerce-cloud] now. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @HenryEcker, I'm a bit confused also. For me the synonym should be configured from the oldest tag. In this case, in the synonyms from [tag:hybris], I should see [tag:sap-commerce-cloud]. But currently it's done in the reverse way. Maybe it's the good way to do but I don't see how people can upvote it since they won't have any rep on the new tag.

Comment: Rep doesn't matter for moderators who can make the synonyms as needed (as Zoe did here). Generally we prefer the current name of the product. One of the primary reasons for this is that moving forward new questions will be more likely looking for the current product name sap-commerce-cloud than the older name hybris.

Comment: The inability to create synonyms in newer tags is more an issue with the tag synonym system. A system that could really use some improvements IMO, but that's, again, a separate issue to this synonym request.

Comment: Thanks @ZoestandswithUkraine, it looks good now :).

Comment: @HenryEcker, yes I opened an other post : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419190/improve-the-synonym-feature-to-upvote-a-request-based-on-the-reputation-score-on. Maybe a minor request but I hope it could be implemented one day.