# Improve the synonym feature to upvote a request based on the reputation score on both tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

This post follows an issue I had about two tags that need to be synonyms : [Merge hybris into sap-commerce-cloud, based on product's new name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419187/issue-with-tag-synonyms-feature)

**To summarize** :

- A user U1 answered a lot of questions with a tag T1
- The name of T1 has been changed to T2
- T2 is proposed as a synonym of T1 (from the T2 tag page)
- U1 has no reputation in T2 and can't upvote the synonym
- U1 can't set a synonym in T1 because it's proposed as a reverse synonym (step 3)

**Result** : The synonym stays in pending until people answer enough questions with T2 tag to upvote the synonym.

**What I propose** : Instead of checking the reputation of T2, why not check the reputation of T1 and/or T2 to allow users to upvote the synonym. Users will mostly have rep in T1 and it makes sense to accept their upvotes in this case.

Comment: The synonym voting is so broken, it is mostly diamond users that make synonyms. Lots of tiny tags need to be synonymized, where there are no users with enough rep in either tag to do so. Your suggestion fixes an important chunk of the issues, but I'd take it further and allow users with 20k rep to vote on any synonym suggestion. Those users can freely edit tag wikis, we trust them with that too.

Comment: This is a problem on other sites, too; it might be worth posting on [meta.se].

Comment: Related: how do we make people actually vote for synonym suggestions in the first place? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305405/407651

Comment: The problem with this (the synonym system) is not that it's hard to use, it's that its hard to use, lack discoverability and non-intuitive. Solving only the "voting" will do nothing with the other to problems. I prefer discoverability first, and then the other two things.